# path alias for 'edit' not loading correct page under 'admin/'

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have a content page that just editors need to see. So I set the pathauto to something like `'admin/page-title'`. The edit-path is `'admin/page-title/edit'` accordingly.

When trying to open the node in edit mode however, the first page of admin section is displayed instead of the edit form – as found under `'admin/'`.

This basically is not really a problem – just took me some time to figure out that actually the '*admin*' part of the URL is causing the problem. I would however really like to keep that URL structure since it would make the path consistent to the actual internal content structure.  Any suggestion how I could get this work? Any pointers would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because paths defined through `hook_menu()` implementations have the precedence over path aliases. The System module defines the admin menu item, which is a *catch-them-all*, since Drupal, for a non existing path like node/1/not-defined-from-any-module, will show node/1. This also happens for not existing path aliases that partially match a path defined from a module; if you try to access admin/not-existing-alias, Drupal will return the page at admin.
Notice that in the case of a non existing alias that partially matches an existing one (e.g. path-alias/sub-path-alias/not-existing-sub-path versus path-alias/sub-path-alias), Drupal will not show the page at the path for the existing alias (in my example, path-alias/sub-path-alias).

Also, the Pathauto module doesn't define path aliases for node/1/edit; for that, you need the [Sub-pathauto (Sub-path URL Aliases)](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module.

> The Drupal Path module matches only full URLs when creating SEO-friendly aliases. This module extends that behavior by also matching known sub-paths and replacing them with their respective alias.
>
> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased URL users/admin/contact instead. This also includes Views URLs taking a node as argument (e.g. node/%/yourview), in short, every URL that is based on, or extends, an existing alias. In combination with the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module it is possible to get rid of all remaining exposed internal non-administrative URLs.

Comment: but i can still have nodes with a url like `'admin/page-title'` –– which should then also be 'overwritten' by the `hook_menu()` if I understood you correctly, or?

Comment: The Pathauto module alone doesn't define aliases for node/1/edit. For that, you need the SubPathauto module.